# Why does my gedit "open" pulldown not show any recent documents?

Tags: gedit

gedit used to show recent documents in an "open" pulldown, but that list has been empty recently. It has been this way for a while now (by while, I mean weeks) and I can't pinpoint any one change that preceded the problem.

[image: No items found]

Where did my list of files I recently edited in gedit go?

Comment: Did you alter any privacy settings?

Comment: No, I did not alter any privacy settings

Comment: hi! check the answears to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308949/gedit-3-6-1-how-to-increase-the-number-of-recent-files-from-its-default-of-5)

Comment: Bingo. Works. Voting to call this a duplicate even tho I asked first.