# Gedit 3.6.1, how to increase the number of recent files from its default of 5?

Tags: files, gedit, history

Ubuntu 12.10, gedit 3.6.1

This won't work:

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set /apps/gedit- /preferences/ui/recents/max_recents 30
```

Modifying this file as root won't work either:

```
cat /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.gschema.xml |grep rece -C 1
```

EDIT: there is nothing at `gconf-editor` either.

Is it hard coded? In order to increase the number of recent files in gedit from its default of 5 will I need to find, "fix" and recompile gedit with the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti)?

Comment: I only use geany now btw :>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `dconf-editor`, this value can be found in the schema under `org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui`. The value that you want to change is called `max.recents`.

[image]

`dconf-editor` can be installed from USC here:

[image: Install via the software center]

or from a command line using: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Comment: worked thanks! btw, about all these configuration tools, this is so confuse, we have gconf-editor, dconf-editor, gconftool-2, I think there is more also.. would be easier if they made something unified like linux-regedit...

Comment: @AquariusPower please no regedit! I agree on "unified tool", but regedit is not the way to go :D

Comment: @Zelphir my bad choice of words, you are right lol!

Answer (score 4):

There exists as well a possibility to achieve this without installing additional software:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/ui/max-recents "uint32 10"
```

Or:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents "uint32 10"
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo: gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents "uint32 10"

Comment: Welcome to AU! You can [edit] your answers (and questions) if you feel they're incorrect or incomplete.

Comment: Using gsettings, i don't get this to work. Although I can set the parameter, gedit still only shows 5 recent files!

Comment: @RobinManoli Did you restart the application when you tried?

Anyway, the question would be, how one figures that config string out with no graphical interface to list all available string continuation options at each level.

Comment: For Pluma (Gedit fork): `gsettings set org.mate.pluma max-recents "uint32 10"`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the dconf-editor (see first answer on this page) on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it worked without a hitch. The steps include:

1. In terminal: sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
2. In dash, find and launch dconf Editor
3. In dconf Editor left pane, expand org -> gnome -> gedit -> preferences
4. In dconf Editor left pane, select ui
5. In dconf Editor right pane, double-click the value next to 'max-recents'
6. Type new value (I entered 20).
7. Press Enter
8. Close Configuration Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Cant make recent files higher than 10 anymore. Use gedit-plugins and enable Quick Open workaround described below:

[Can't increase the number of recent documents in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249107/cant-increase-the-number-of-recent-documents-in-gedit)