# How to increase the number of recent files in Pluma from its default of 5?

Tags: pluma

The way [for gedit](https://askubuntu.com/q/308949/181242) doesn't work.

Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, Pluma 1.12.2 from the repositories.

Command-line solution without the use of external programs is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui`, use `org.mate.pluma`:

```
$ gsettings set org.mate.pluma max-recents 10
$ gsettings get org.mate.pluma max-recents
10
```