# Can't increase the number of recent documents in gedit

Tags: 20.04, gedit, dconf

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit my list of recent documents in gedit returned to the default 10 only.

Normally this could be easily changed with `dconf`, but now `dconf` can't find the   `ui max-recents` schema for gedit.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

This option has been removed in recent versions of gedit, so the `dconf` key was also removed with it.

A workaround is to use the [*Quick Open* plugin](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-quick-open.html.en), which shows more than 10 recent files. As a bonus, you can also search for files with it. Just follow these steps:

1. Install, if you haven't already the `gedit-plugins` package, which contains the *Quick Open* plugin along with a bunch of other useful plugins:

   ```
   sudo apt install gedit-plugins
   ```
2. Enable the plugin by clicking the hamburger menu <kbd>≡</kbd> → *Preferences* → *Plugins* and enable *Quick Open* (see screenshot below).

   [image: enable Quick Open]
3. After that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open a window which shows your recently opened files and also allows to search for files to open.

   [image: Quick Open]

Comment: This is a great workaround ! Will save me lots of time. Thanks Beast !

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 the Quick Open plugin is available without installing `gedit-plugins`.